# What type of (3-pin) connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector, fan

I need to replace a fan (DC, Blower, 60x60x23mm) but the replacement unit I got (Delta AUB0712HH-C) came with the wires unfinished, which I'm aware is likely standard procedure but was news to me. And with that development I am officially out of my depths.

There are so many similar looking (Molex PicoBlade?) connectors I can't find an exact match and all of my local repair shops are no help until I find the connector. I'm finding it is very hard to find when you don't really know what you are asking for...

I've attached pictures along with some scale elements. The female portion is ~3mm W x ~4mm L x 2mm D (where D is the thickness of the plug; and L is the length of the portion that is inserted) and there the measurements of all 3 dimensions would be slightly larger if measuring the crown that sits atop the portion that is inserted... I see a lot of connectors listed by a single measurement (in mm) but which one is it?

Any additional pictures needed, please just let me know. And thank you so much.

[image]

And this is how the wires were finished; they went into the end pictured in the above photo lineup (bottom, center).

[image: :]

And THIS is the proper header... sorry, ladies and gentlemen.

[image]

Comment: cut off the old connector and splice it onto the new fan

Comment: the plug has 4 pins and the cable connector has 3 pins

Comment: "And THIS is the proper header... sorry, ladies and gentleman." Well, dang! OK, back to square one.

Answer (score 3):

The header looks like a low-profile wire-to-board connector, 1.25 mm pitch, crimp.

My [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_1p2&s=PicoBlade%20(3w)&fl=0020000010000000000000002000100000-54c-%7C1.25%7C4%7C%7C%7C) identified it as:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/picoblade) - [PicoBlade (3w)](http://www.literature.molex.com/SQLImages/kelmscott/Molex/PDF_Images/987651-3691.PDF) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/20?k=PicoBlade)

[image: Molex 0533980490]

{Digikey}

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an [Adam Tech 1CH-A-03](https://app.adam-tech.com/products/download/data_sheet/240643/1ch-a-xx-data-sheet.pdf).

This is a 1.25mm Picoblade plug:
[image]

Comment: No, if you look at [the header](https://www.digikey.com/short/3h2zmrbv), you'll see that it has 4 walls. OP's header has 3 walls. Also, the pitch is 1 mm, and OP's pitch appears to be 1.25 mm.

Comment: Hmm the center-top picture looks like 1.0mm pitch to me.  PicoBlade also does not have a triangular pin 1 marking on the plug.

Comment: Check this [picture of a Picoblade header](https://media.digikey.com/photos/Molex/53398-0490.jpg). Doesn't it look just like OP's? But you're right, the plug looks slightly different.

Comment: I agree the header looks like a Picoblade header, but I think the pitch is off.  I've attached a picture of a Picoblade to my original post.

Comment: the pictures show 1 mm pin spacing ... they also show incompatible number of pins

Comment: OK, slight user error here.  I asked the shop to send me a picture of the header (because they have the unit and I don't) and he sent me a picture of the adjacent one.  And in my haste to get this posted so I can get the part ordered, I didn't notice until the whole 4-pin thing started.

Comment: (I've updated the original post to include the proper header)

Comment: @VIR, as it turns out, we were both correct, you about the plug, and I about the (wrong) header.

Comment: @QuePasaNisiMasa, I believe you should accept VIR's answer.

Comment: PEC steel rule. Nice.

Comment: $15 well-spent.

Answer (score 3):

> And THIS is the proper header... sorry, ladies and [gentlemen].

OK, with the updated information, this is what my [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_1&fl=0000000000000000000000002000100000-50c-%7C1%7C%7C%7C%7Cfff) reveals about the plug:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam tech - [1SH + 1CH](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/4/page_234-240-12264.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/3h2zmrbv)
- [Amphenol](https://www.amphenol-icc.com/product-series/minitek-1-00mm-wtb.html) - Minitek 1.00mm - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/vb5n9hwp)
- Harwin - M40-301 M40-401 + M40-110 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/7vqjmjnm)
- [JST](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=231) - [SH](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSH.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/rjw79rdv)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/picoclasp) - [Pico-Clasp 202396 203556 203557 203558 203559 501331 501568 + 501330](http://www.literature.molex.com/SQLImages/kelmscott/Molex/PDF_Images/987651-6111.PDF) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/20?k=Pico-Clasp)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/intersection/high-performance-interconnects.html?tab=pgp-story) - [HPI-1 (unlatch)](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773713-2_HPI_QRG_EN&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/5mj9zmq8)
- [Wurth](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/em/connectors/wire-to-board/wr_wtb/wr_wtb_1_00_mm) - WR-WTB 665 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/j2qtb5j4)

Note that the first line item is what @Vir said. Therefore, they were correct.